# Minted Package escaping code for SQL

Tags: minted

I'm using `minted` package in LaTeX to display SQL statements however, I have a variable which it confuses with the keyword "ORDER" in SQL. How can escape this? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is a LaTeX related question: `minted` uses the `pygments` Python library for formatting.

Comment: @m0nhawk - Maybe an answer that explains what escaping is possible with minted is on topic?  There is both a pre-pygments and a post-pygments phase with minted.